# Getting the value of a clicked cell that has been loaded from parse?

Tags: ios, parsing, uitableview, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController where I loaded certain information. I want to get the value of the cell you click to open another table with the information with the class name of the cell you clicked. I had tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work, I think that i am not taking the value of the label of the cell because the error says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)'

I am using this code:

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Hospitales";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"Hospital";

    // The title for this table in the Navigation Controller.
    self.title = @"Hospitals";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 10;
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}

[query orderByAscending:@"Location"];

return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Hospital"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@", [object objectForKey:@"Location"]];

return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView CellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell.textLabel.text = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"People" sender:self];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Check that a new transition has been requested to the DetailViewController and prepares for it
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"People"]){
    //Get the selected data
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString* hospitalData = _data[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController]setHospital:hospitalData];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so safe to rely on the UI to get the data you need, as a result you are violating the core MVC concept.

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
              didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"People" sender:self];
}
```

**prepareForSegue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"People"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize the _data, do i have to make a variable with that name?

Comment: Yes exactly it would be your datasource like a NSARray for example. The one you have used to set the text on the label

Comment: It still shows the same message : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)' I  don't know why it doesn't take the value.

Comment: please show me your datasource, also `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: I changed the code in the initial question that is the code I have now in my project but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It sill doesn't work, do i have to load the value in the next view in certain way?

Comment: Do you still get the error? and Yes you will have to handle the object on the next view